# What does chi p(q) mean?

Tags: econometrics, stata

It is a beginner question but I did not find a good explanation so I am asking here. Hope that I received the help from the community.

Today I run a joint null test individually like that

```
test (tau0=0) (tau1=0) (tau2=0)
```

And the result is

```
( 1)  tau0 = 0
 ( 2)  tau1 = 0
 ( 3)  tau2 = 0

           chi2(  3) =    1.12
         Prob > chi2 =    0.7717
```

I am wondering what does the numbers **2** and **3** in **chi2(3)** mean. I did a search from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test) but I did not fully get it.

Comment: You should probably mention the program you are running.

Comment: @Giskard it is STATA, thank you

Comment: I don't want to be mean, but you could just google this, if you just enter chi(3) stata into google you get answer in the first result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is most likely a [$\chi^2$ distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution) with a degree of freedom of 3. From Wikipedia:

> In probability theory and statistics, the chi-squared distribution [...] with k degrees of freedom is the distribution of a sum of the squares of k independent standard normal random variables.